# Firebase Analytics debugging mode?

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am starting to use Firebase Analytics in Android. I am familiar with Google Analytics and I would like to switch to FA. In GA, you can use another tracking-id when you're debugging (in tracker-config.xml), than the tracking ID used in release versions. That is to prevent the many times you start up the app during debugging, to appear in the Analytics results. Is there a way to achieve that effect in Firebase Analytics? I couldn't figure out how.

My app also doesn't have that many users, so most of the analytics would come from me using the app while debugging.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

One way to approach this would be to register a second "debug" app in your Firebase project that uses a different package name. Then, the google-services.json will contain two mobilesdk_app_id's -- one for your debug app and one for your release app.  These are effectively your tracking IDs.  Their reporting will be kept separate in the Analytics reports for your project.

Comment: So I should change the package name for debug release?